# how do you stop a page for starting up when a opening chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I open up my browser a it open with a search engine called tikotin, tried blocking but every time I open it now, it opens up but the warning that it's blocked and can't use it -_-

Comment: Never block. Its not solving the problem, just trying to bypass it. Solve it at the root.

Answer (score 0):

The first things you want to check is what the homepage is set to. Then in about:config you can find some more advanced settings where this might be stored.

Also, make sure you check for spyware, because spyware often sets an infectious page as homepage.

Lastly, check the url of your shortcut. Some spyware injections alter ALL your shortcuts and set the startpage through there.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably been infected with malware: the malware doesn't let you to set a different start page when you open your browser. Follow this steps to remove the malware:

1. Download [this tool](https://toolslib.net/downloads/viewdownload/1-adwcleaner/) called AdwCleaner: it will allow you to remove the infection(s).
2. Run it as administrator and start the scan.
3. Once the scan has finished proceed to remove the infections by clicking on the "Clean" button.
4. The program will ask you for restart your computer, do it.
5. Verify if the problem was solved.

As an extra, when you are done, you can uninstall the tool, just open it and click
the "Uninstall" button, this will also remove the quarentined malware.